# What can be said about number-theoretic properties of the solid angle measures of polytopal cones in the weight lattice of sl(n)?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, nt.number-theory, euclidean-geometry, polytopes

The following question might be elementary — it is too far from my area of expertise to tell.  It has shown up in my research in an interesting way, which I will not go into here, but I'm happy to tell you about it in private if you get in touch with me.

To begin, take the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$, and the vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$, and its orthogonal $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane.  Let's call this hyperplane $\mathfrak h$; it is an $(n-1)$-dimensional Euclidean space.  There is the orthogonal projection $\mathbb R^n\to\mathfrak h$.  Define a lattice $\Lambda$ inside $\mathfrak h$ as the image of the standard $\mathbb Z^n \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ under this projection.  Unless I am mistaken, this lattice is the weight lattice of $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$.  (It's one of those weight or root or coroot or something lattices, anyway.)

Pick $n-2$ points in $\Lambda$; then there is an $(n-2)$-dimensional hyperplane in $\mathfrak h$ passing through those points and the origin.  With one more bit of data (an orientation, say) those points pick out a half-space (say as those $x\in \mathfrak h$ so that a certain determinant is positive).  For want of a better term, let me call an *integer polytopal cone* (the closure of) a region formed by taking intersections and unions of finitely many such half-spaces.  (Is there a better name for such an object?)

For any integer polytopal cone $C$, I can measure its *solid angle measure* (normalized so that the solid angle measure of $\mathfrak h$ is $1$).  Namely, let $B$ denote the unit ball in $\mathfrak h$, and $\operatorname{Vol}$ the standard Euclidean volume function; then the *solid angle measure* of $C$ is $|C| = \operatorname{Vol}(C\cap B) / \operatorname{Vol}(B)$.

I am interested in understanding what types of numbers can be $|C|$.  <strike>I would love the answer to the following question to be "yes", but I am not optimistic:</strike>

> If $C$ is an integer polytopal cone, is $|C|$ necessarily rational?

As I say, I am not optimistic.  For example, it seems very unlikely that $\arctan(\sqrt{3}/5)/\pi \approx 0.106147808$ is rational.  This number already shows up for $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$. **<edit>** In the comments below, Anonymous has made clear the following.  In general, $|C|$ is not rational.  For example, $\arctan(\sqrt{3}/5)/(2\pi)$ is the angle measure of an integer polytopal cone for $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$, and it cannot be rational, by the links that Anonymous suggested. **</edit>**

So the more general questions are:

> What are the number-theoretic properties of the solid angle measures $|C|$?
>
> Is there a large class of integer polytopal cones $C$ for which one can assure that $|C| \in \mathbb Q$?

**<edit>** I'm particularly interested in the second question.  I have a construction that uses these angle measures for *some* integer polytopal cones.  I would be happiest if my construction were to stay within $\mathbb Q$.  If there is a large, easily tested class of cones $C$ for  which $|C| \in \mathbb Q$, then perhaps I can show that my construction stays within this class.  **</edit>**

(Finally, I have no idea how to tag this question, because it is far from my area of expertise.  So I've picked a few tags, and welcome suggestions for retagging.)

Comment: You correctly described the weight lattice; the root lattice is the intersection with that hyperplane rather than the projection.  Unfortunately, that's the only part of your question I have much intelligent to say about.

Comment: It seems your pessimism is justified. If theta is a rational multiple of $\pi$, then $2\cos(\theta)$ is an algebraic integer. But if $\theta = \arctan(\sqrt{3}/5)$, then $2\cos(\theta) = 5/\sqrt{7}$.

Comment: Have you looked into "scissors congruence"?

Comment: @Bruce: Could you explain the reason 'scissors congruence' might be related?  Or is it just a hunch?

Comment: @Anonymous: Well, that seems to answer the first question.  I'm sure that "If theta is a rational multiple of π, then 2cos(θ) is an algebraic integer" is well-known, but it is not well-known to me — can you point me to somewhere to read more?

Comment: @Theo: I learned about it on math.stackexchange: Two proofs are at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79861/arctan2-a-rational-multiple-of-pi

Comment: @Alexander: I was thinking of taking the "scissors congruence" group over the rationals. Then the volume is a group homomorphism to the reals. Then I had in mind to reinterpret this in terms of $K$-theory and the Borel regulator. 

Answer (score 1):

$S_n$ acts on the set of cones, and preserves the solid angle measure.  If you consider the $n!$ rotations of the cone by elements of $S_n$, and except on the union of some hyperplanes, the number of such cones covering an arbitrary point $x$ in $\mathfrak h$ is constant, say $N$, then the solid angle measure of the cone is $N/n!$.

This argument applies to the cones of the Coxeter arrangement (i.e. the cone generated by the fundamental weights $(1,0,\dots,0), (1,1,0,\dots,0),\dots,(1,\dots,1,0)$ and its $S_n$ translates); the $n!$ rotations are disjoint except on their boundaries and cover $\mathfrak h$, so their volumes are $1/n!$.

Less obviously, this argument also applies to the cone generated by a set of simple roots.  This is worked out in Graham Denham's short paper "[A note on De Concini and Procesi's curious identity](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.2263)".